# Trouble with Left Excluding JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Table private inherits id's from table public. I'm trying to select entries in public within some distance of $lat,$lng whose id's are not found in private.

```
SELECT a.id, a.data, a.lat, a.lng,
  (a_distance_function(a.lat,a.lng,$lat,$lng)) as a.distance 
FROM public a
WHERE (a.lng BETWEEN $lng1 AND $lng2) AND (a.lat BETWEEN $lat1 AND $lat2) 
HAVING a.distance < $dist 
LEFT JOIN private b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE b.id is NULL;
```

But the MariaDB error isn't much help to me. Syntax error near '.distance FROM USMAP a WHERE a.lng BETWEEN -xx.xxx AND -xx.xxx'

Comment: You have two where clauses, and a join in the wrong place. in short, the query syntax is broken.

Comment: The two where clauses work without the join does the join limit the number of allowed wheres?

Comment: no, it can't possibly work. a select query can only have ONE `where`.

Comment: I see what you're saying, only one `WHERE` keyword. I was interpreting "clauses" as what the `WHERE` operates on (i.e. `(a.lng BETWEEN $lng1 AND $lng2) AND (a.lat BETWEEN $lat1 AND $lat2)`). Removing the `JOIN` in my previous comment also removes the second `WHERE`.

Comment: sorry, yeah, should've said "where statements". you can have as many clauses as you want in the one `where` you're allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JOIN`'s must occur before adding any conditions to your query:

```
SELECT a.id, a.data, a.lat, a.lng,(a_distance_function(a.lat,a.lng,$lat,$lng)) as a.distance 
FROM public a 
LEFT JOIN private b 
ON a.id = b.id 
WHERE b.id is NULL
AND a.lng BETWEEN $lng1 AND $lng2 
AND a.lat BETWEEN $lat1 AND $lat2 
HAVING a.distance < $dist
```

Comment: Point taken on the JOIN. The examples I've seen didn't touch on WHERE statements besides those that are part of the Join.

However, the error persists '.distance FROM public a LEFT JOIN private b on a.id = b.id WHERE b.id is NULL A'

Comment: There is no discernible error in the query unless the function `a_distance_function()` is not proper @OBoud

Comment: If I replace lines 2-4 with  `FROM public WHERE`  (removing the first `AND` from the following line) and remove the `a.` from each occurrence of the column names it works.

If I replace lines 3-4 with `WHERE` and leave in all the `a.`'s it does not.

`distance` and `a` are both aliases, correct? Is there a problem with an alias of an alias?

Comment: Removing the alises in the distance calculation worked:
`a_distance_function(lat,lng,$lat,$lng) as distance` and `HAVING distance < $dist`
But I'm not sure why.

Comment: Awesome! Without being able to test on your system I wouldn't be able to know why the alias' are a problem.